# SendMessage not working

Tags: vb6, sendmessage

I am trying to automate a login process. I need to pass 2 times tab and a keydown(for a drop down) and enter event in order to login. I am using below code

```
 parenthwnd = FindWindow1(vbNullString, "APPName")
  retvalue = SendMessage(parenthwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_TAB, 0)
  retvalue = SendMessage(parenthwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_TAB, 0)     
  retvalue = SendMessage(parenthwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_DOWN, 0)
  retvalue = SendMessage(parenthwnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_DOWN, 0)
  retvalue = PostMessage(parenthwnd, BM_CLICK, 0, 0)
```

While the tab events are working. I am not able to get the keydown and enter event to work.
Is there something I am missing.

Comment: Try using PostMessage instead of SendMessage. It may help.

Comment: Thanks Mukul I have tried PostMessage and SendKeys but none of them worked.

Comment: @YogeshY: if the dropdown is windowed, you may navigate the window hierarchy to get that window handle, it's not the same as `parenthwnd`. Use Window Inspector or something like this. Then, you can find the children by their `WindowClass`..

Comment: @deblocker thanks, I did tried to do the same but I was not able to get any child window handles and hence unable to pass anything. Is there anything else for same.

Comment: is there any other way of doing this ?

Comment: @YogeshY: try send a CB_SHOWDROPDOWN - if this doesn't work, post a screenshot from Winspector

Comment: @deblocker thanks for looking, but can't find this working too. Winspector is not tool I can download at my organization.

Comment: @YogeshY: you could use Spy++ it's an official Microsoft tool delivered with the Windows SDK in Visual Studio since 20+ years

Comment: @deblocker I used spy++ but there is only one  other window available,  when I get its handle I am not able to do anything through it.

Comment: @YogeshY: it's fine, use the [Finder Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460750.aspx) to hook your login window, press the keys by hand, then look at the [Messages View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460726.aspx). You will easily find out which one is the right hWnd and what messages and params you need to send.